# Consistent link colors across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design, usability

I'm often waffling about from site to site within the Stack Exchange network. I love viewing the highest voted questions within certain sites/tags. Something that irks me is that the color of links which should show me whether or not I've visited a particular question before are not consistent from site to site.

Now, which colors should be chosen may be a question for UX. Any color within reason, as long as they are consistent across sites, would be helpful!

Comment: That might be a challenge, considering that different sites have different designs and picking just one set of link colours might not work well everywhere.

Comment: I agree we could use *more* consistency in links, but a single color just can't work. Some sites are even light on dark, there's too much variation

Comment: @AnnaLear; I guess you're right, but Brocka has a point.

Comment: Different styles is OK, but this is indeed confusing. I am a regular visitor of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/ and the style for (un)visited seem exactly opposite.

Comment: Yes, I, too, am often confused as to which are the visited vs. unvisited links in the HNQ section of the site, since the colours change from site to site, and often seem to be the reverse of what I expect.